# Ignore quote in SQL query in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, datagridview, quotes

I have a method within a class that writes all of the rows and columns from a table in my database. However, when I try to fetch data from myTable in my DB with `readAllFromTable("myTable", myDataGridView)` it fails because the selected table is wrapped around quotes, so the query looks like this:

> SELECT * FROM "mytable"

...When it I need it to look like this:

> SELECT * FROM mytable

Source code:

```
 Public Sub readAllFromTable(table As String, datagrid As DataGridView)
    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM @table"

    sqlQuery = New MySqlCommand(sql, login.connection)
    sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", table)

    sda.SelectCommand = sqlQuery
    sda.Fill(dbDataSet)
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
    datagrid.DataSource = bSource
    sda.Update(dbDataSet)
End Sub
```

Comment: as per usual, placeholders can represent only **VALUES**. they cannot be used to replace sql keywords or identifiers.

Comment: you also dont need an Adapter, DataSet and BindingSource just to read one table

Comment: Depending on the version you can use dynamic sql using the prepare, concat and execute functions.